# C# System.NullReferenceException during setting slider value to text property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have this simple slider project. I wanna show slider value in TextBox.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <TextBox x:Name="sliderValue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
     <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="20" Value="5" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged"/></Grid>

        // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
            var slider = sender as Slider;
            string value = string.Format("{0}", slider.Value);
            sliderValue.Text = value;
    }
```

In last line I am getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at slider_test.MainPage.slider_ValueChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1 e)
>      at .......

Could anyone explain me what is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: You are trying access null object. Please check for null slider object after you cast.

var slider = sender as Slider;

if(slider != null)
{
 string value = string.Format("{0}", slider.Value);
 sliderValue.Text = value;
}

Comment: Slider is not null but I got the same error. TextBox sliderValue is null though.

Comment: @petrppe Update code string value = string.Format("{0}", slider.Value); by  string value =  slider.Value.ToString(); debug code and see result. IF I guess right prblem in your string format.

Comment: @Jaihind I tried but same error.

Comment: @petrppe Use e.Newvalue istead of slider value. I geva an answer give a look.

Comment: @Jaihind Thanks, but no progress again. I guess there must be some problem with that TextBox...

Comment: @petrppe Seems Ok Textbox. I made update in my ans give a look. mat there is some cross thread problem.

Comment: @Jaihind Wow! Such a little thing and "so complicated" solution. I have never heard about Dispatcher class. I guess I should learn about it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but may be this will help you.

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        { 
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    string value = string.Format("{0}",  e.NewValue);
                    sliderValue.Text = value;
                }); 

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using XAML by Binding slider value to TextBlock text.

```
        <Slider x:Name="SliderValueText" ValueChanged="SliderValueText_ValueChanged"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="440"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="20"
                Value="5" />
        <TextBlock Height="30"
                   Text="{Binding Value,  ElementName=SliderValueText}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />


private void SliderValueText_ValueChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    string value = string.Format("{0}", e.NewValue);
    MessageBox.Show(value);
}
```

It is one of the option. Here you need the slider value. So I am storing in the variable "value". That's what I am displaying in MessageBox. But it is least case to try...

Comment: I know about this way but I can't use this because I need to work more with value later and put some other string to textbox and so on.

Comment: Yes, but still I need to set that "value" variable to the text property of textbox and do that inside slider_ValueChanged method.

Comment: So... YOu don't want to use Bind the slider value using XAML, lLike this. `Text="{Binding Value,  ElementName=SliderValueText}"`

Answer (score 0):

In this way use e.NewValue for polling changing a value:

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Value changed and value is " + e.NewValue.ToString());  
    }
```

But for labels simply use XAML bindings:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="someLabel"  
           Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"
/>
```